# Why i get errors while Installing Python modules?

Tags: python, pip

i am using:

1. Python 3.10.1
2. Pip 21.2.4
3. Python Project in an virtual enviroment

My Problem:
Everytime i try to install any package (for instance opencv) i get the following error:

```sh
(einstieg) C:\Users\User\Python\pyproj>pip install python-ldap
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/python-ldap/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/python-ldap/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/python-ldap/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/python-ldap/ 
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/python-ldap/ 
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/python-ldap/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/python-ldap/ 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-ldap (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-ldap 
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: 
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ 
(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
```

I tried some of the trusted hosts hints i found but nothing worked.
my be somebody knows where my problem come from?

Comment: Are you on a network that requires a proxy and/or do you have a proxy configured?

Comment: yeap a proxy, i'll need the download packages...

Comment: pip has configuration for proxies, I believe; setting that correctly should help, and you'll only need to do it once (as opposed to always manually downloading packages)

Answer (score 2):

This issue is related to SSL Certificate. Try pasting this in CMD:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```

If that doesn't do the work, try this:

```
pip install requests==2.18.4 --user --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org
```

If you have installed `Fiddler` earlier, uninstall it, that might be the cause of the problem.

And lastly if none of this works, then you need to directly download the files from wheel. This means that first you'll download the package on your PC, then write `pip install your-package.whl`.

You can find OpenCV and other package's .whl files online easily.

Comment: Hi, i am new in python only as a general information :) 
I tried the both CMD orders but both are not working...
So i need to download the packages from "wheel"...
So what is wheel and where do i find it ? :)

Comment: you can either get from the package's website, if it has one, or if you search on google, `opencv-python .whl` or any package. Manually downloading the .whl file a.k.a `wheel file` should fix most of the downloading issues

Comment: i found the problem: i need correct paths to the modules. thats all...

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that worked for me. The error suggests there is a problem with the proxy configuration / SSL certificate. In bash, I executed the following.

```
 1. export PIP_PROXY=http://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PROXY_PORT>

 2. pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

I had initially tried to use the command below but I could not get past the subprocesses. The SSL error came up again.

```
pip --proxy=https://<IP_ADDRESS>:<PROXY_PORT> install <PACKAGE_NAME>
```